# Azure REST API Certificate

Tags: api, rest, azure, certificate, token

I am making API calls to Azure REST to get some information about Azure resources to further on monitor Azure services.
I'm trying to make calls in the Postman, using JWT in the header, but some calls throws me errors like this:

- `ForbiddenError`
  The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.

Why some calls work but some of them throws an error like this.

According to error, I need to get a certificate, but I don't really know how to do it and what to do it...

So, anyone could help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you share some of the code of one that isn't working?

Comment: https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/monitoring/alertrules       Here is one of them

Comment: I just realize that https://management.azure.com/... works just fine, but https://management.core.windows.net/... don't. Anyone can help me with this problem, please?